# Configuration of UTF-8 in bootstrap contact form using using PHPMailer

Tags: php, utf-8, contact-form

I'm using this contact form
https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form?utm_content=cmp-true

In English it works great, but the second language of the website is Cyrillic and I didn't succeed to configure it
Only 'labels' work with Cyrillic, but I need the data from the <input..> to be received correctly from the mail.

Only 'labels' work with Cyrillic, but I need the data from the <input..> to be received correctly from the mail.
/I'm using the second variant/

Comment: I highly recommend [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). You need to ensure you use UTF-8 in every single step of your application workflow.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer allows you to set char encoding:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Also be sure to save your PHP file using UTF-8 encoding without BOM.

[Docs](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#property_CharSet)